# Google Chrome 28 doesn't play mp4 videos

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, mp4

I have an issue at the moment where I cannot get any .mp4 videos to play on Google Chrome 28, this only happens on Windows 7 machines, but not all of them.

As it stands, I was able to replicate the issue on three Windows machines out of five.

Even if I enter the direct URL to the .mp4 file in the address bar, Chrome still won't play it.

Can anyone here replicate this issue?
I have used a few different .mp4 files to test, but here's one:
http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

I would appreciate any help.

Note: By going Chrome Advances settings and turning off "Use hardware acceleration when available" Chrome is able to play the video, however that option is turned on by default, so not the perfect solution to the problem.

Thanks a lot.

UPDATE: updating the video drivers fixed it, but again... not the ideal solution...

Comment: Do the affected machines have anything in about:flags turned on, other than the default? Does devtools report anything? Does the issue still happen with devtools open/closed?

Comment: Hey Jake, I did a clean install of Chrome, so all settings are as default, the only setting I changed was the one mentioned above. Tried with Devtools opened & closed, makes no difference.

Comment: What about Canary on the same machines? That would indicate if a fix is on its way

Comment: Also, just after it fails, have a look in chrome://gpu/ and see if there's anything interesting in the log

Comment: Hey Jake, the only thing that fixed it was by updating the drivers.

Answer (score 1):

we also had this problem... Both Webm and theora/ogg worked fine in chrome and the mp4 video worked fine on IE9 and in firefox. Just chrome fails.

We also manage to fix this by updating the video drivers (intel HD on a DELL PC), so looks like a problem in the H.264 acceleration used in chrome and old intel drivers